# QField layers displaying as 'read only'

Tags: qgis, layers, qfield

Utilising QField, QFieldCloud, and QGIS - I have previously been adding layers on QGIS and seamlessly collecting data in the QField. However, one vector point layer is displaying on QField as 'read only' despite the layer configuration being editable in the 'data sources' properties. I have attempted to create a new layer, which also appears as 'read only' on QField. This occurs despite the other layers in the project being editable. I have checked that the paths are correct.

Relatively new to QField and unsure how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: Check layer configuration for QField. Is lock geometry checked?

Comment: Lock geometry is not checked. Still cant seem to figure this one out